# How to generate a boolean condition during runtime in C++?

Tags: c++, math, range, conditional-statements

I want to be able to generate a boolean condition during the runtime based on the states of some variables. My task looks simple at first. I have a large `if () else if ()` statement what needs to determine if the number is in a certain range. It then does something depending on whether that number is inside that range.
Here's **pseudocode** to demonstrate what I want:

```
void fun(int num, int offset = 0) {
    if (0...60) {
         // do something
    } else if (60...180) {
        // do something else
    } else if (180...240) {
    } else if (240...360) {
    }
}
```

The first if statement should work like this:

```
if (0 >= num && num <= 20) {
    // do something
}
```

The caveat here is that in addition to `int num`, there is another parameter passed in, which I call the `offset`. The structure of the code here, including the `do something` inside the `{ }` is the same. The only things that need to change are are ranges, based on the value of the offset. By the way, this is **not** a default parameter here, it is just pseudocode demonstrating what the value of `int offset` was passed in.

```
void fun(int num, int offset = 120) {
    if (120...180) {
         // do something
    } else if (180...300) {
        // do something else
    } else if (300...360) {
    } else if (360...120) {
    }
}
```

That last `else if ()` statement has been giving me some trouble.

```
} else if (360...120) {
}
```

What I'm actually trying to write here is:

```
} else if (num >= 360 || num <= 120) {
}
```

The reason for this is that my `int num` may have a value > 360. However, in that case for the purpose of my application it has to "wrap around" and be treated as a value `0...120`.

This is for a mathematical application here. Whenever you have `int num` > 360, you go around the full circle and you end back at 0 where you started. So that is the effect which I want to achieve.

I don't want to write extra functions. I want my code to be generic because many different values for `int num` and `int offset` may be passed into my function. I want to generate the necessary conditions during the runtime based on the value of `int offset`.

The main problem here is that in the first situations, when `int offset = 0` my condition is

```
} else if (240 >= num && num <= 360) {
}
```

However, for a different offset we wrap around and so I have to change the format of **the entire condition**! For example, when `int offset = 120`, as shown above:

```
} else if (num >= 360 || num <= 120) {
}
```

The problem is that in the first situation I had the `&&` in the last `else if ()`, but now I have the `||` to convey the same meaning. What I'm looking for is a way to be able to manipulate the *operators* inside the conditional statements as mere `char`s in a `string`, then "paste" the completed condition into the `if ()` statements **during the runtime**!

What's even worse is that this "wrapping around" can occur inside any one of the `if ()` statements, not just the last one. It is based on the value of the `offset`.

I can't use preprocessor tricks, because I want this to work during the runtime. Maybe it is possible to use function pointers or something for this, but I don't know how to do that. Please note that the `...` above is **not** real *C++ code*, it is *pseudocode*! I'm aware that there is a "range-based" switch statement in C++, but I can't use that because of the "wrapping around" property mentioned above.

Comment: "I'm aware that there is a "range-based" switch statement in C++"  - no there isn't

Comment: `else if (360...120) {` could be replaced by `else {` since you covered all the other cases already. And it is not clear to me what the logic is for the cases. is it always +60 then +120 then +60 then +120 ?

Comment: Anyway, why don't you just do `(num + offset) % 360` and use the fixed cases from your first example

Comment: what if offset is `1`?

Comment: @IłyaBursov Then the first range would be `1...61`. The last range would be `241...360`, and `360` would "wrap around" to `0`.

Comment: @M.M That `%` solution is really good idea!